# 2 Ways to start and stop an instance ec2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

So i have found on the [Api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#startinstances) from Amazon that you can start and stop the instance with this

> $result = $client->startInstances([/* ... */]);

and also like this

> $promise = $client->startInstances([/* ... */]);

So here is my question. Are there any diffrences between the $promise and the $result.

Comment: youll have to show more code   as right now $promise and $result seems to be the same thing just a different variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP SDK for EC2 documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#startinstances) that you linked in your Question:

> Each of the following operations can be created from a client using `$client->getCommand('CommandName')`, where "CommandName" is the name of one of the following operations. Note: a command is a value that encapsulates an operation and the parameters used to create an HTTP request.
>
> You can also create and send a command immediately using the magic methods available on a client object: `$client->commandName(/* parameters */)`. You can send the command asynchronously (returning a promise) by appending the word "Async" to the operation name: `$client->commandNameAsync(/* parameters */)`.